# Find and Replace for Javascript, to change link, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, replace, hyperlink, find

Ok here is my problem:  I have a google analytics code that looks like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

and I would like to replace this line:

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http:/') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'
```

With this line:

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js'
```

BUT I CANNOT EDIT THE ORIGINAL CODE, I can only add to it.  Is there a way to create a code that finds and replaces this line somehow?

Please help,

Grey

Comment: Take note that `java` and `javascript` are two completely different things.

Comment: Are you trying to augment a script right in the browser or do you have access to server part?

Comment: Why can you add to, but not edit, the code?

Comment: I pity the guy who did this `'https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http:/'` instead of this `document.location.protocol + '//'`

Comment: hmm. Why can't you modify the script? That script will fire even if you try to replace the src. Then just by "changing" the src, the doubleclick will not all of a sudden fire.

Comment: Hi, I have access to the server but cannot edit the script, is it possible to to ad a line to somehow counteract what's there and replace it with the line would like?

Comment: @Niall It's there because they (Google) also prefix the host name with `ssl` for https and `www` for http. Otherwise, they could just use a protocol-less URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about placing your modified script above the current one and then repressing the existing script?  Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
<script type='application/x-suppress'>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: I like the idea but unfortunately I can only add after the code

Comment: Ah okay, I have another idea.  I'll post it.

Comment: If you don't need that _gaq variable just delete those three lines above the self-invoking anonymous function.

Comment: So the suppress application, I understand it suppresses, but does it only suppress the function of that script?  If so can I can just delete the variables of the code I am adding, since they are the same as the one that already exists and just replace the function? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: It suppresses the whole script including the function and variable.  So if you still need the variable then keep it in your script.  If not, then there's no real reason for the function anyway.  You could simply insert the script directly: `<script src="http://stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js"></script>` (followed by `<script type='application/x-suppress'>`)

Comment: Ok I understand, then the google tag assistant, does it just basically search your source code and say that there are 2 tags because both tags are there, but doesn't take into account that one of them is purposely not functioning?

Comment: Yeah, that may be the case.  I'm not sure how the tag assistant searches for tags, but that suppress script prevents the script from running and bringing in the ga.js file so there shouldn't be any functionality of the code.  It may be that the assistant simply looks for a tag with stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js in it...  In that case you could try also having code below the script to replace (or remove) that line...

Comment: Now I'm curious... If you add this script below the ga.js script that you can't touch does that prevent the tag assistant from finding a tag for ga.js?  Here's the line to add:  `<script id="scriptFixer" type="text/javascript"> var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'); var scriptCount = scripts.length; var regex = new RegExp('.google-analytics.com/ga.js'); for (var i = scriptCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) { var script = scripts[i]; if (script.id !== 'scriptFixer' && (script.innerHTML.match(regex) !== null || script.src.match(regex) !== null)) { script.remove(); } }`

Comment: You would still want to include the suppress line and the dc.js script.

Comment: Hey Mike, unfortunately I cannot add anything AFTER the code that I am trying to suppress so I cannot test the above code.  I appreciate all the help, I think the suppress code is doing the trick.  The only way I will be able to check is if I start to receive Demographic information, which is what the new line of code allows.  Says it takes 24 to 48 to start to flow, so I'll write back and let you know.  Thank you again!!

Comment: Hey Mike, Looks like the suppress code did it!!  Thanks so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].remove();
    document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].remove();
    var _gaq = [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js'
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Mike you're awesome, let's talk about this, because I'm a beginner, can you explain the concept of this?  It looks like there is a command to remove the previous script and then replaces it?

Comment: Oh also, is this specific enough to remove only that script or does it remove other scripts?

Comment: Sure, that command gets all script tags (an array) and then gets the first element in the array and removes it.  Since the script you provided puts the google analytics script before the 0th script, that first call will delete that google analytics script.  The second call assumes that the script you provided is the first script on the page (now the 0th again) and then deletes that script.  This might not be the case...

Comment: It will remove whatever script is at the index you provide.  If you open up the console in your browser when the page loads and run the command document.getElementsByTagName('script') you should see an array with all the scripts on the page.

Comment: Hey Mike, I ran the command above to check the scripts and it looks like you're right, the analytics code is before the 0th script, then there are a few other scripts.  The script that has the analytics code is the 4th script.  So the first call takes care of the analytics before the 0, but how do I now call out the 4th script to be deleted and replaced?

Comment: To get the 4th script you would use index 3.  So you could change that second call to document.getElementsByTagName('script')[3].remove();

Comment: Ok Im going to try this out and Ill get back to you, thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Another option that doesn't require you to be careful about the indices of the scripts is as follows (notice that the new script has an id):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
<script id="scriptFixer" type="text/javascript">
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var scriptCount = scripts.length;
    var regex = new RegExp('.google-analytics.com/ga.js');
    for (var i = scriptCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var script = scripts[i];
        if (script.id !== 'scriptFixer' && (script.innerHTML.match(regex) !== null || script.src.match(regex) !== null)) {
            script.remove();
        }
    }
    var _gaq = [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js'
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Mike.  Ok I've taken another look at it and I was incorrect.  I can only add code BEFORE the line not after.  I'm trying your suppress code and it doesnt seem to be working.  Is there another line I can add to ignore the next script which is the one with the old line?

Comment: Ok let me clarify, I have run the suppress line that you have provided, and I believe that it did in fact suppress the script because the line that is created in the 0th script is now the correct one.  When I run document.getElementsByTagName('script') in the console the 0th script is now:  [
<script type=​"text/​javascript" async src=​"http:​/​/​stats.g.doubleclick.net/​dc.js">​</script>​
,  However when I run google tag assistant it still shows as 2 analytic tags and has a warning for 2 scripts that contain _gaq and _gat variables.  Is it not suppressing the variables?

Comment: It looks like I did put the scripts in backward for that answer though...  I'll fix that now - could that be why it didn't work?  It works for me in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari.  I don't have access to IE at the moment...

Comment: Yeah, those variables will still show up because they're in your script too.  Well at least _gaq is but you could delete it.  E.g.:  delete _gaq;

Comment: Does it suppress the script after or before the suppress line?

Comment: It suppresses the script *after* the line.  The code was backward above.  Now it's fixed but the ga.src lines aren't quite right.  I'll fix them.